# How to write in stdout repeatedly with php

Tags: php, symfony, console, stdout

I want to develop a cli `debug` feature for my app which will print out all information about a `URI` request such as memory usage, routes, elapsed time, sql queries, etc...

How can i write this information to the console.When i activate my program from terminal it will wait for a request then prints information to the output.I came out with this hacky code:

```
$this->console->writeln("<info>Enter Ctrl+C to exit.</info>");
while(true) {
    sleep(5);
    $this->console->writeln("<info>$profileInfo</info>");
}
```

I'm using Symfony2 Console component for that the tag `<info>` is just a pseudo code.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're running this from the terminal, why not just use `echo` in your PHP code then?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're making a HTTP request to a PHP page but using the console component purely to achieve debug logging, is that right?

If so, then you'd be far better off using a 'logger' service (such as [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog)) to do your logging into a file, then you can watch for changes in real time via the console by running `tail -f /path/to/LOG_FILE`. If you're using the full-stack Symfony2 framework then this is already available as the `logger` service ([example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html)).

Also, I'm not sure if you're already using the [Stopwatch](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/stopwatch.html) Symfony2 component to do your profiling, but if not then I'd definitely recommend it.

EDIT: Even if you're running your code via the command line, logging to a file is still a good option. Otherwise simply use `echo` as jszobody suggested.

Comment: I used symfony component for the sake of stability.it saves me some time to reinvent the wheel and write some code for managing a cli app(getting arguments or options & output formatted(coloring) information).my problem was about providing a way to actually write some information repeatedly to output.Like when you run php -S localhost:8000 it gives you the web server log information until you stop it(press Crtl+c or Crtl+d).